# Why does my Hamburger menu didn't work on other page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hamburger-menu

currently i'm working on my portfolio website, i've created hamburger menu using Javascript and it works on my homepage, but when i created another page, i copied everything from `<header>`, but the humburger menu didn't work. I am sure that i already change the path of the file. Also i'm using sass. Is there anything i missed?

**HomePage Header HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/logo-yellow.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="/../fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <title>igeegi</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
           <nav>
                <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="./images/main-logo.png" alt="igeegi"></a>
               <div class="openMenu">
                   <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
               <ul class="mainMenu">
                    <li><a href="#works">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#resume">Résumé</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <div class="closeMenu">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </div>
               </ul> 
           </nav>
       </header>
 <script src="./app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Header style**

```
header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.15);
    position: fixed;
    z-index:10000;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;

    .mainMenu {
        display:flex;
    }
}

nav .mainMenu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: $color-Dark;
    padding: 30px;

    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 400;

}

nav .mainMenu li a:hover {
    color: #616161
}

nav .openMenu {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: $color-Dark;
    margin: 10px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav .mainMenu .closeMenu, i {
    font-size: 30px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
    nav .mainMenu {
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: $color-Yellow;
        transition: top 1s ease;
        display: none;
    }
    nav .mainMenu .closeMenu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 20px;

    }
    nav .openMenu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

**Hamburger menu Javascirpt**

```
const mainMenu = document.querySelector('.mainMenu');
const closeMenu = document.querySelector('.closeMenu');
const openMenu = document.querySelector('.openMenu');

openMenu.addEventListener('click',show);
closeMenu.addEventListener('click',close);

function show(){
    mainMenu.style.display = 'flex';
    mainMenu.style.top = '0';
}
function close(){
    mainMenu.style.top = '-120%';
}
```

**Sub Page Header HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/logo-yellow.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="/../fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <title>works</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
           <nav>
                <a href="../index.html" class="logo"><img src="../images/main-logo.png" alt="igeegi"></a>
               <div class="openMenu">
                   <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
               <ul class="mainMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Résumé</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <div class="closeMenu">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </div>
               </ul> 
           </nav>
       </header>
 <script src="../app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try and look at your console, it will most likely tell you why it's not working

Comment: it says nothing about related to the hamburger menu @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: Have you tried to add something like `console.log("test")` in your js file and see if it fires from both sites?

Comment: I am also stuck with the same issue. Can you share what was the solution?